# Inno Setup: Always run task through interface, never run through command line

Tags: inno-setup

There's a part of my setup that I never want to run when calling it through command line, but always run it through the interface.

I was doing this through a [task], and simply not passing that particular task in the command line options.

My problem is, when running this setup through the interface, I don't even want to give this option to the user, and I can't find a way to hide a task from the setup interface.

Is there a way to hide this task? Or another, better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no natural difference between running the setup from the "interface" (presumably Explorer?) and running from a command prompt.

Maybe you mean `/silent`? If so, use the `WizardSilent()` function.

If you don't want it to be silent, you can pass your own `/skipXYZ` parameter that you then check using `GetCmdTail()` or `{param:...}`

Comment: Ok, I meant the difference between running from interface (next -> next -> finish thing) and running from command line as /silent (forgot to mention that)

Comment: What are X Y and Z in the skip parameter?

Comment: Random text to signify that the custom parameter you check for can be called anything you want.